# Switching Between First and Third Person Views (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, perspectivecamera, camera-view

I'm trying to implement a simple 3D environment that a robot can walk around. I want the user to be able to switch between first and third person views for the robot.

I have implemented the robot, and a simple area with a few other objects. Currently, the view is 3rd person. I've been using the gluPerspective function to try to implement a first person that turns when the head turns (head turn already implemented), but it seems like no matter the parameters I use, I can't get the toggling to work. It always stays the same. Is there a simpler way to achieve this effect than what I've tried so far? Is what I'm doing not working because of my approach?

The following code suffices to set the perspective to first person, however it does not follow the head of the figure as I expect. I can initialize it on top of him, but I'm not sure how to make the robot move with the camera, as the landscape effectively moves around him. I was thinking I could sort of 'fake' this by removing the robot while in first person. Thoughts? :

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
double atx = xPos + cos(lookAngle);
double atz = zPos + sin(lookAngle);
double atHeight = eyeHeight + eyeIncline;
gluLookAt(xPos, eyeHeight, zPos, atx, atHeight, atz, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```

I have tried calling a switch statement in a keyboard function to switch to 3rd person. Keyboard call looks something like this:

```
void key(unsigned char k, int x, int y)
{
if ( k == 27 ) /* Escape */
  exit(0);
else if ( k == 86 ) { /* 'v' for view change */
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluLookAt(0, 0, -20, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0); //Look down z-axis

}
glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

But it doesn't work. No toggling is done.

Code below:

```
#define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK

#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <math.h>

#define TORSO_HEIGHT 5.0
#define UPPER_ARM_HEIGHT 3.0
#define LOWER_ARM_HEIGHT 2.0
#define UPPER_LEG_RADIUS  0.5
#define LOWER_LEG_RADIUS  0.5
#define LOWER_LEG_HEIGHT 2.0
#define UPPER_LEG_HEIGHT 3.0
#define UPPER_LEG_RADIUS  0.5
#define TORSO_RADIUS 1.0
#define UPPER_ARM_RADIUS  0.5
#define LOWER_ARM_RADIUS  0.5
#define HEAD_HEIGHT 1.5
#define HEAD_RADIUS 1.0

double cubeX[] = { 5.0, 5.0, 5.0 };
double cubeY[] = { 3.0, 3.0, 3.0 };
double cubeZ[] = { 7.0, 5.0, 3.0 };
double cubeR[] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
double cubeG[] = { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
double cubeB[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };

double xPos = 2.0, zPos = 5.0;
double eyeHeight = 4.5;
double eyeIncline = -0.5;
double lookAngle = 0.0; //In rads

double posIncr = 0.25;
double thetaIncr = 0.1;

typedef float point[3];

static GLfloat theta[11] = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
        180.0,0.0,180.0,0.0}; /* initial joint angles */
static GLint angle = 2;

GLUquadricObj *t, *h, *lua, *lla, *rua, *rla, *lll, *rll, *rul, *lul, *lf1, *lf2;

double size=1.0;

void torso()
{
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(-90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
gluCylinder(t,TORSO_RADIUS, TORSO_RADIUS, TORSO_HEIGHT,10,10);
glPopMatrix();
}

void head()
{
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0.0, 0.5*HEAD_HEIGHT,0.0);
glScalef(HEAD_RADIUS, HEAD_HEIGHT, HEAD_RADIUS);
gluSphere(h,1.0,10,10);
glPopMatrix();
}

void left_upper_arm()
{
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(-90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
gluCylinder(lua,UPPER_ARM_RADIUS, UPPER_ARM_RADIUS, UPPER_ARM_HEIGHT,10,10);
glPopMatrix();
}

void left_lower_arm()
{
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(-90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
gluCylinder(lla,LOWER_ARM_RADIUS, LOWER_ARM_RADIUS, LOWER_ARM_HEIGHT,10,10);
glPopMatrix();
}

void left_finger1()
{
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(-90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
gluCylinder(lf1,FINGER_1_RADIUS, FINGER_1_RADIUS, FINGER_1_HEIGHT,10,10);
glPopMatrix();
}

void left_finger2()
{
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(-90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
gluCylinder(lla,LOWER_ARM_RADIUS, LOWER_ARM_RADIUS, LOWER_ARM_HEIGHT,10,10);
glPopMatrix();
} 

void right_upper_arm()
{
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(-90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
gluCylinder(rua,UPPER_ARM_RADIUS, UPPER_ARM_RADIUS, UPPER_ARM_HEIGHT,10,10);
glPopMatrix();
}

void right_lower_arm()
{
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(-90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
gluCylinder(rla,LOWER_ARM_RADIUS, LOWER_ARM_RADIUS, LOWER_ARM_HEIGHT,10,10);
glPopMatrix();
}

void left_upper_leg()
{
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(-90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
gluCylinder(lul,UPPER_LEG_RADIUS, UPPER_LEG_RADIUS, UPPER_LEG_HEIGHT,10,10);
glPopMatrix();
}

void left_lower_leg()
{
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(-90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
gluCylinder(lll,LOWER_LEG_RADIUS, LOWER_LEG_RADIUS, LOWER_LEG_HEIGHT,10,10);
glPopMatrix();
}

void right_upper_leg()
{
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(-90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
gluCylinder(rul,UPPER_LEG_RADIUS, UPPER_LEG_RADIUS, UPPER_LEG_HEIGHT,10,10);
glPopMatrix();
}

void right_lower_leg()
{
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(-90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
gluCylinder(rll,LOWER_LEG_RADIUS, LOWER_LEG_RADIUS, LOWER_LEG_HEIGHT,10,10);
glPopMatrix();
}

void drawCube( int i )
{
double x = cubeX[i];
double y = cubeY[i];
double z = cubeZ[i];

glColor3i(1, 0, 0); //Red cube
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(x,y,z);
glutSolidCube(1);
glPopMatrix();

glColor3i(0, 1, 0); //Green Cube
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(x,y,z);
glutSolidCube(1);
glPopMatrix();

glColor3i(0, 0, 1); //Blue Cube
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(x,y,z);
glutSolidCube(1);
glPopMatrix();

glColor3i(0, 1, 1);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(x,y,z);
glutSolidCube(1);
glPopMatrix();

}

void drawCubes(void)
{

glLoadName(1);
drawCube(0);

glLoadName(2);
drawCube(1);

glLoadName(3);
drawCube(2);

/* Set name back to '0' to indicate background. */
glLoadName(0);
}

void drawFloor(void)
{
GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0 };
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glNormal3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(-10.0, 0.0, -10.0);
  glVertex3f(10.0, 0.0, -10.0);
  glVertex3f(10.0, 0.0,  10.0);
  glVertex3f(-10.0, 0.0,  10.0);
glEnd();
}

void doDrawing(void)
{

drawCubes();

drawFloor();

/* Everything else is a lighter shade of grey. */
GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = { 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0 };
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
}

void drawEnviro(void)
{
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
double atx = xPos + cos(lookAngle);
double atz = zPos + sin(lookAngle);
double atHeight = eyeHeight + eyeIncline;
gluLookAt(xPos, eyeHeight, zPos, atx, atHeight, atz, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

glPushMatrix();
doDrawing();
glPopMatrix();
}

void display(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
drawEnviro();
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0, 0, -20, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0);
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

glRotatef(theta[0], 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
torso();
glPushMatrix();

glTranslatef(0.0, TORSO_HEIGHT+0.5*HEAD_HEIGHT, 0.0);
glRotatef(theta[1], 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(theta[2], 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glTranslatef(0.0, -0.5*HEAD_HEIGHT, 0.0);
head();

glPopMatrix();
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(-(TORSO_RADIUS + UPPER_ARM_RADIUS), 0.9 * TORSO_HEIGHT, 0.0);
glRotatef(theta[3], 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
left_upper_arm();

glTranslatef(0.0, UPPER_ARM_HEIGHT, 0.0);
glRotatef(theta[4], 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
left_lower_arm();

glTranslatef(0.0, LOWER_ARM_HEIGHT, 0.0);
glRotatef(theta[11], 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
left_finger1();

glPopMatrix();
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(TORSO_RADIUS+UPPER_ARM_RADIUS, 0.9*TORSO_HEIGHT, 0.0);
glRotatef(theta[5], 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
right_upper_arm();

glTranslatef(0.0, UPPER_ARM_HEIGHT, 0.0);
glRotatef(theta[6], 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
right_lower_arm();

glPopMatrix();
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(-(TORSO_RADIUS+UPPER_LEG_RADIUS), 0.1*UPPER_LEG_HEIGHT, 0.0);
glRotatef(theta[7], 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
left_upper_leg();

glTranslatef(0.0, UPPER_LEG_HEIGHT, 0.0);
glRotatef(theta[8], 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
left_lower_leg();

glPopMatrix();
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(TORSO_RADIUS+UPPER_LEG_RADIUS, 0.1*UPPER_LEG_HEIGHT, 0.0);
glRotatef(theta[9], 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
right_upper_leg();

glTranslatef(0.0, UPPER_LEG_HEIGHT, 0.0);
glRotatef(theta[10], 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
right_lower_leg();

glPopMatrix();

glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();
}

void setProjection(void)
{
gluPerspective(60.0, 1.0, 0.1, 100.0);
}

void mouse(int btn, int state, int x, int y)
{
  if(btn==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
    theta[angle] += 5.0;
    if( theta[angle] > 360.0 ) theta[angle] -= 360.0;
    }
  if(btn==GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
    theta[angle] -= 5.0;
    if( theta[angle] < 360.0 ) theta[angle] += 360.0;
    }
    display();
 }

void menu(int id)
{
if (id < 11 ) angle = id;
if (id == 11 ) exit(0);
}

void specialKey(int k, int x, int y)
{
/* Accept commands to move the viewpoint. */
switch (k) {
  case GLUT_KEY_UP:
     xPos += posIncr * cos(lookAngle);
     zPos += posIncr * sin(lookAngle);
     break;
  case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
     xPos -= posIncr * cos(lookAngle);
     zPos -= posIncr * sin(lookAngle);
     break;
  case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
     lookAngle -= thetaIncr;
     break;
  case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
     lookAngle += thetaIncr;
     break;
  case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP:
     eyeIncline += 0.5;
     break;
  case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN:
     eyeIncline -= 0.5;
     break;
  case GLUT_KEY_HOME:
     eyeHeight += 0.5;
     break;
  case GLUT_KEY_END:
     eyeHeight -= 0.5;
     break;
  default:
     return;
  }
  glutPostRedisplay();
 }

void reshape(int w, int h) 
{
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective (65.0, w/h, 1, 1000.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
}

void init()
{
    GLfloat mat_specular[]={1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat mat_diffuse[]={1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat mat_ambient[]={1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat mat_shininess={100.0};
    GLfloat light_ambient[]={0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat light_diffuse[]={1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat light_specular[]={1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat light_position[]={10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 0.0};

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, mat_ambient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glLoadIdentity();
    setProjection();

    //Fill the body parts of the robot
    h=gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(h, GLU_FILL);
    t=gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(t, GLU_FILL);
    lua=gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(lua, GLU_FILL);
    lla=gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(lla, GLU_FILL);
    rua=gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(rua, GLU_FILL);
    rla=gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(rla, GLU_FILL);
    lul=gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(lul, GLU_FILL);
    lll=gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(lll, GLU_FILL);
    rul=gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(rul, GLU_FILL);
    rll=gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(rll, GLU_FILL);
    lf1=gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(lf1, GLU_FILL);

 }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
glutCreateWindow("robot");
init();
glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutMouseFunc(mouse);
glutSpecialFunc(specialKey);

glutCreateMenu(menu);
glutAddMenuEntry("torso", 0);
glutAddMenuEntry("head1", 1);
glutAddMenuEntry("head2", 2);
glutAddMenuEntry("right_upper_arm", 3);
glutAddMenuEntry("right_lower_arm", 4);
glutAddMenuEntry("left_upper_arm", 5);
glutAddMenuEntry("left_lower_arm", 6);
glutAddMenuEntry("right_upper_leg", 7);
glutAddMenuEntry("right_lower_leg", 8);
glutAddMenuEntry("left_upper_leg", 9);
glutAddMenuEntry("left_lower_leg", 10);
glutAddMenuEntry("quit", 11);
glutAttachMenu(GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON);

glutMainLoop();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like everything that's related to *draw* stuff, setting the projection matrix (together with setting the viewport and the modelview matrix) belongs into the drawing code path, in your case `display`. Do not place it in `reshape`. And `init` is completely wrong for doing this.

Comment: I've seen conflicting opinions on this. Stylistically, that may be true, but it has not helped resolve my issue.